# Move the camera relative to looking direction in gluLookAt

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Having a camera located in 3D cube within `display`:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    ...
    glu.gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    ...
}
```

The camera look at the point - `(centerX, centerY, centerZ)`  .

I want to move it relative to its looking direction (forwards, backward, right, left).

What is the operation which I should make on `eye`'s and `center`'s in order to move the camera according to `center` (for each of the above sides)?

**Edit:**

I don't need the implementation  ,just the concept .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,first define a Vector3D point

```
struct tVector3 // Extended 3D Vector Struct
{
tVector3() {} // Struct Constructor
tVector3 (float new_x, float new_y, float new_z) // Init Constructor
{ x = new_x; y = new_y; z = new_z; }

tVector3 operator+(tVector3 vVector) {return tVector3(vVector.x+x, vVector.y+y, vVector.z+z);}
tVector3 operator-(tVector3 vVector) {return tVector3(x-vVector.x, y-vVector.y, z-vVector.z);}
tVector3 operator*(float number)    {return tVector3(x*number, y*number, z*number);}
tVector3 operator/(float number)    {return tVector3(x/number, y/number, z/number);}

float x, y, z;  // 3D vector coordinates
};
```

then define what camera has to do

```
void CCamera::Move_Camera(float speed)     //UP AND DOWN
{
tVector3 vVector = mView - mPos;

mPos.x = mPos.x + vVector.x * speed;
mPos.z = mPos.z + vVector.z * speed;
mView.x = mView.x + vVector.x * speed;
mView.z = mView.z + vVector.z * speed;
mPos.y = mPos.y + vVector.y * speed; 
mView.y = mView.y + vVector.y * speed; 

}


void CCamera::Rotate_View(float speed)
{
tVector3 vVector = mView - mPos;    // Get the view vector

mView.z = (float)(mPos.z + sin(speed)*vVector.x + cos(speed)*vVector.z);
mView.x = (float)(mPos.x + cos(speed)*vVector.x - sin(speed)*vVector.z);
}


void CCamera::Strafe_Camera(float speed,bool YAxis)    // MOVE LEFT AND RIGHT
{
tVector3 vVector = mView - mPos;    // Get the view vector

tVector3 vOrthoVector; // Orthogonal vector for the view vector

vOrthoVector.x = -vVector.z;
vOrthoVector.z = vVector.x;

mPos.x = mPos.x + vOrthoVector.x * speed;
mPos.z = mPos.z + vOrthoVector.z * speed;
mView.x = mView.x + vOrthoVector.x * speed;
mView.z = mView.z + vOrthoVector.z * speed;

}
```

And in Display()

```
gluLookAt(objCamera->mPos.x, objCamera->mPos.y, objCamera->mPos.z,
          objCamera->mView.x, objCamera->mView.y, objCamera->mView.z,
          objCamera->mUp.x, objCamera->mUp.y, objCamera->mUp.z);
```

where mPos is camera position (described in x y z coordinates),mView is the point you're looking at.ObjCamera is created in initlializeGL();

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks  , can you describe what is the operation on `center` and `eye`  ?

Comment: Take a look at Move_Camera(float speed) method.(you have to know that vVector is the distance between the camera position and where its looking at).If u want learn from basics I would suggest you this http://www.morrowland.com/apron/tut_gl.php and this http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/loading_and_moving_through_a_3d_world/22003/ (its C++ but its easy to translate)